# How to call API, looping over axios.get() adding ?offset=<param> and exit loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, airtable

I have an API call to http GET data, 100 records at a time.

It has a GET URL param:  `?offset=`

that can be set to fetch all results.

Initially I believe offset would be 0, would have to test, but then 101, 201, 301.

the first fetch would get records 1..100.

I am starting with this (code below), fetching the first 100 records, but I'm not sure what a loop would look like here, because I have no idea how many records there ultimately are, and I do not know how to exit the loop.

If anyone has experience with this, and could take this code sample, modify and post as a reply, it would be super greatly appreciated.

---

Also within the await `axios.get()`, does the call to `processRecords()` need to be

`await processRecords()`, and then also `async processRecords()` ?

I get errors, if I specify `await processRecords()`, am trying to understand this.

---

This is an actual working example, that will get the first 100 records, and I would like to loop, incrementing `?offset=<next start number>` until all are fetched.

```
function processRecords() {
    console.log('processRecords()');
    // do stuff
}

const processTable = async () => {
    const url = `https://api.airtable.com/v0/` + atApiBaseKey + `/` + atTableName;

    const headers = {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + atApiKey,
        'Content-Type': "application/json"
    };

    try {
        let offset = 0;    // no initial offset
        let params = {
            maxRecords: 100,
            offset: offset
        };

        /**
         * how to loop here over await axios.get() ?
         *
         * what would a for loop look like here, incrementing offset by 100
         * each time?
         *
         * and how would the loop exit?
         *
         */

        await axios.get(url, {params: params, headers: headers})
            .then((response) => {
                processRecords(response.data.records);  // process 100 records

                //console.log(response.data);
                //console.log(response.status);
                //console.log(response.statusText);
                //console.log(response.headers);
                //console.log(response.config);
                console.log('')
            });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
};
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Airtable provides a JavaScript SDK which has some helper functions to complete this task.  https://github.com/Airtable/airtable.js.  You can also look at the interactive documentation at https://airtable.com/api to see examples for how to iterate through each page of records.

Not documented is the function called `all` which manages the iteration for you and pulls in all records:

```
const Airtable = require("Airtable");

var base_id = "YOUR_BASE_ID";
var base = Airtable.base(base_id);
var table_name = "YOUR_TABLE_NAME";

var table = base.table(table_name);
table.select().all()
  .then((records) => {
    console.log(records);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("ERR: ", err);
  });
```

If you want to use axios and create your own client, you can.  The `offset` parameter is returned from the previous API response.  If it is present in the API response, then you have more pages to fetch.  If it's not present, then you've iterated through all records in the given table:

```
const axios = require('axios');

const processTable = async () => {
  const url = `https://api.airtable.com/v0/` + atApiBaseKey + `/` + atTableName;

  const headers = {
    'Authorization': "Bearer " + atApiKey,
    'Content-Type': "application/json"
  };

  let offset = null; // no initial offset

  // use the pageSize parameter to control the number of records in each page
  // maxRecords controls the total number of records the API will ever return
  let params = {
    pageSize: 1,
    offset: offset
  };

  // create an array to hold all of our records
  let records = [];

  try {
    // make the request
    let response = await axios.get(url, {
      params: params,
      headers: headers
    });

    // push the resulting records into our array
    records.push(...response.data.records);

    // check if we have an offset
    offset = response.data.offset;

    // continue looping and making requests until there is no more offset
    // if there is no offset, then return the list of records
    while (offset !== undefined) {
      params = {
        offset: offset
      };
      let response = await axios.get(url, {
        params: params,
        headers: headers
      });
      records.push(...response.data.records);
      offset = response.data.offset;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
  return records;

};
processTable()
  .then((records) => {
    console.log(records);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log("ERR: ", err);
  })
```

Would highly recommend using the Airtable JS SDK to remove this complexity.

Answer (score 0):

while function was making my program crash, here is a recursive version.

```
const axios = require('axios')

let results = []
let baseURL = "https://api.airtable.com/v0/baseid/tablename"
let headers = { authorization: "Bearer " + 'yourkey' }
let params = { pageSize: 100}

axios({
    baseURL: baseURL,
    headers: headers,
    params: params
}).then(res =>  { results.push(...res.data.records)
    params.offset = res.data.offset
        const axcall = () => { axios({
            baseURL: baseURL,
            headers: headers,
            params: params }
            ).then( 
                res =>  { results.push(...res.data.records)
                    params.offset = res.data.offset

                    if (res.data.offset !== undefined) {
                    return axcall() }
                    else { // after all calls ends
                      console.log(results)
                    }
                }
            ).catch(e => console.log(e))
            }
            axcall()
}).catch(e => console.log(e) );
```